# How to add user to SignalR Group in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, signalr

i wanna add user to signalR group but it says failed.
my android code to add user in group as below

```
HubConnection connection = new HubConnection("http://www.planetskool.in/");
    HubProxy proxy = connection.createHubProxy("ChatHub");


    try {
        //Log.d(TAG, "connection.start()...");
        SignalRFuture<Void> awaitConnection = connection.start();
        // Log.d(TAG, "started");
        awaitConnection.get();
        // Log.d(TAG, "got");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        /// Log.e(TAG,"InterruptedException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        //Log.e(TAG, "ExecutionException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SignalRFuture<Void> isGroupCreated2 =  proxy.invoke("JoinGroup", loginUserInfoId);
    Log.d("isGroupCreated", "isGroupCreated2 = " + proxy.invoke("JoinGroup", loginUserInfoId).isDone());

    proxy.on("broadcastMessage",
            new SubscriptionHandler1<String>() {
                @Override
                public void run(final String status) {
                    //getApplicationContext().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    //public void run() {
                    Log.d("SignalRResult=", status);
                    if(status.toUpperCase().equals("False".toUpperCase())) {
                        new SyncMessageFromServer().execute();
                    }
                    else {
                        new SyncGroupMessageFromServer().execute();
                    }
                    // }
                    //});
                }

            }
            , String.class);
```

and the code in ChatHub in MVC Web Application is

```
public Task JoinGroup(string groupName)
    {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }

public void SendAll(string rUId, string message)
        {
            Clients.Group(rUId).broadcastMessage(message);
        }
```

How can i make it work to send notification to particular user